# iOS 8 Family Sharing on, but not showing shared purchases

Tags: ios, family-sharing

After my wife and I upgraded our devices to iOS 8, I turned on a family sharing account so we could use those features.

It's on, and shows up on both of our phones as being part of a family. I also see the shared reminders and calendar. Also, her devices show up in my Find my iPhone.

What doesn't show up is purchases. If I go to iTunes or to the App Store, under purchased, I do not see her, nor any area for family purchases. It looks as it always has.

We have two totally separate iTunes accounts, always have.

Also, as a note - I have gone through everything on Apple's support page (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5449) and no changes. Basically, it notes to make sure you are logged into the right accounts, everyone is set up to share, and the apps support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download a new free app & see if it jogs the server.

From http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/18/how-to-start-an-ios-8-family-sharing-account-to-share-apps-music-movies-more

Comment: This worked, thank you! Right after I downloaded a free app, I checked both and they were right there immediately.

Comment: Do you have the name of the free app that you downloaded? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Anything. You just need to jog its elbow, wake it up.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.  On the iPad, I got to show my other family members by completely quitting the iTunes Store and App Store apps (two press the home button and swipe up to quit the app).  Once I reopened the app, the family members started showing up.